# Ошибка при попытке установите pygtk на мак

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygtk

Почему на мак не ставится pygtk?

```
pip3 install pygtk
```

```
Collecting PyGtk
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/18/fa4f2de77500dd62a314fd845ff6e903ac2ce551164cb421c5750969f799/pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y7/hkq439yd0f34lmysz9xsjcz00000gn/T/pip-install-f8h85urn/PyGtk/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/y7/hkq439yd0f34lmysz9xsjcz00000gn/T/pip-install-f8h85urn/PyGtk/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/y7/hkq439yd0f34lmysz9xsjcz00000gn/T/pip-install-f8h85urn/PyGtk/
    Complete output (4 lines):
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Вот тут причина: `Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.`

Comment: Скорее всего в репозитории модуля искать нужно: pypi, github, не знаю. По вашей же теме: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52653079/5909792 Еще можно попробовать `brew install pygtk`

Comment: Не хило мне брю машину перелопатил.Установилась куча всякой штуки.
Но GTK встало на python 2 , а юзаю python 3.Да еще такое ощущение, что  мне еще раз установился python2( по мимо системного ).

Comment: Удалите его нафиг :) Это при `brew install pygtk` случилось? А команда по ссылке `brew install pygobject3 --with-python@2 gtk+3`?

Comment: Кстати вопрос если я напишу`brew uninstall pygtk`, то удалиться и весь другой хлам ,которой по английски маскируется под словом dependence

Comment: Зависимости могут и остаться, не уверен, но мб brew достаточно умный, чтобы удалить зависимости, особенно если нет других установленных библиотек с такими же зависимостями

Comment: Нет ,блин ,удалил только pygtk, а я не запомнил точно ,что его dependence ,а что нет  (хоть логи сохраняй)

Comment: Судя по всему команда ставит GTK `brew install pygobject3 --with-python@2 gtk+3 ` для второго питона тоже.

Как поставить для третьего (и желательно чтобы работало в венве пайчарма)?